# Adding comments for "<%@" directives in asmx file

Tags: c#, asmx

I was attempting to comment out a directive on an asmx file:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="test" Class="test" %>
```

when i realised, i have no idea what the syntax is to do so.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use
    <%--    --%>

for server-side comments, or Ctrl-K Ctrl-C in Visual Studio

[image]

Comment: Actually, to my surprise the hotkeys did not work, that's why i ended up having to ask the question haha. strange. oh well. Thanks for the syntax.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 - keyboard shortcuts work for me: an alternative is to use the menu: Edit / Advanced / Comment Selection.

Comment: Both hotkey and menu do "HTML comments" for me, because file is recognized as XML. There is no asmx filetype (I assume if it were, those commands should work ok)

Comment: Actually, my server just crashed! `There can be only one 'webservice' directive.` So the comment was not recognized as a comment